# Slow query in Postgres while joining tables with 10M rows all join column indexed

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have three tables with 10M,1.2M and 7M (domain,company and tech). I left join company and tech tables with domain on id column. id column is btree indexed on all three tables.I select 1000 rows from this based on filter (a surrogate key column) which is also btree indexed.

```sql
select d.domain_id,m.id,c.*,t.* 
from
    prospects_v6.domain_info d
    left join master.m_all_tags m using(tag_id)
    left join prospects_v6.tech_info t on t.domain_id = d.domain_id
    left join prospects_v6.company_info c on c.domain_id = d.domain_id
where
    d.domain_id is not null
    and d.prospector_id in (
        '20881',
        '94259',
        '232564',
        '86408',
        '189655',
        '10654',
        '12916674',
        '12816939',
        '136487',
        '137920',
        '41978',
        '29876',
        '88698',
        '92173',
        '211585',
        '139373',
        '89140',
        '5006',
        '39649',
        '83666',
        '136533',
        '10949',
        '12812242',
        '81684',
        '11873',
        '139736',
        '216078',
        '192526',
        '89299',
        '154159',
        '89204',
        '93744',
        '99332',
        '136447',
        '12832241',
        '82964',
        '137684',
        '81011',
        '86456',
        '47800',
        '89787',
        '138707',
        '86821',
        '88741',
        '139209',
        '89695',
        '10929',
        '89580',
        '92113',
        '248744',
        '93381',
        '137100',
        '13422',
        '135922',
        '139672',
        '89625',
        '32440',
        '138471',
        '139002',
        '12886918',
        '139481',
        '137298',
        '221742',
        '93941',
        '82996',
        '12862710',
        '134327',
        '136711',
        '117993',
        '84739',
        '209561',
        '25124',
        '12907898',
        '156867',
        '25313',
        '205498',
        '162553',
        '89648',
        '137976',
        '137767',
        '137968',
        '137779',
        '12861976',
        '139083',
        '137579',
        '176214',
        '87495',
        '86364',
        '243901',
        '12828901',
        '92564',
        '139901',
        '90791',
        '136781',
        '139073',
        '12861423',
        '12815159',
        '100902',
        '137628',
        '139911',
        '137316'
    ) order by c.domain
```

I tried running this query with enable_hashjoin= off and it runs in 40 secs. When I run the same query with enable_hashjoin=on query runs for 2min 40 secs.

EXPLAIN ANALYZE for the query uses only hashjoin when enable_hashjoin=on when turned off optimizer used merge and nested loop joins.
enable_hashjoin=off;

```
Gather Merge  (cost=24678052.73..25181243.43 rows=4312762 width=1646) (actual time=43027.778..43115.778 rows=101 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Sort  (cost=24677052.71..24682443.66 rows=2156381 width=1646) (actual time=42592.810..42592.826 rows=34 loops=3)
        Sort Key: c.cmp_web_traff_rank, c.cmp_domain
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 136kB
        Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 169kB
        Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 142kB
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=3906925.51..19828928.98 rows=2156381 width=1646) (actual time=41688.783..42592.598 rows=34 loops=3)
              ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=3906925.07..3926857.09 rows=2156381 width=501) (actual time=41688.730..42591.754 rows=34 loops=3)
                    Merge Cond: (d.domain_id = c.domain_id)
                    ->  Sort  (cost=2771941.43..2777332.38 rows=2156381 width=221) (actual time=19427.296..19427.317 rows=34 loops=3)
                          Sort Key: d.domain_id
                          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 50kB
                          Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 56kB
                          Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 52kB
                          ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=2052810.47..2088114.20 rows=2156381 width=221) (actual time=19342.801..19419.225 rows=34 loops=3)
                                Merge Cond: (d.tag_id = m.tag_id)
                                ->  Sort  (cost=1967900.66..1973291.61 rows=2156381 width=193) (actual time=18860.436..18860.448 rows=34 loops=3)
                                      Sort Key: d.tag_id
                                      Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 40kB
                                      Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 43kB
                                      Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 42kB
                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on domain_info d  (cost=0.00..1328299.43 rows=2156381 width=193) (actual time=900.630..18860.238 rows=34 loops=3)
                                            Filter: ((domain_id IS NOT NULL) AND (prospector_id = ANY ('{20881,94259,232564,86408,189655,10654,12916674,12816939,136487,137920,41978,29876,88698,92173,211585,139373,89140,5006,39649,83666,136533,10949,12812242,81684,11873,139736,216078,192526,89299,154159,89204,93744,99332,136447,12832241,82964,137684,81011,86456,47800,89787,138707,86821,88741,139209,89695,10929,89580,92113,248744,93381,137100,13422,135922,139672,89625,32440,138471,139002,12886918,139481,137298,221742,93941,82996,12862710,134327,136711,117993,84739,209561,25124,12907898,156867,25313,205498,162553,89648,137976,137767,137968,137779,12861976,139083,137579,176214,87495,86364,243901,12828901,92564,139901,90791,136781,139073,12861423,12815159,100902,137628,139911,137316}'::integer[])))
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 3433181
                                ->  Sort  (cost=84909.81..86388.82 rows=591603 width=36) (actual time=452.739..522.965 rows=261724 loops=3)
                                      Sort Key: m.tag_id
                                      Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 43144kB
                                      Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 43144kB
                                      Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 43144kB
                                      ->  Seq Scan on m_all_tags m  (cost=0.00..12015.03 rows=591603 width=36) (actual time=0.023..124.137 rows=262143 loops=3)
                    ->  Sort  (cost=1134983.65..1138208.40 rows=1289903 width=288) (actual time=22248.525..22870.536 rows=920674 loops=3)
                          Sort Key: c.domain_id
                          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 385312kB
                          Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 385312kB
                          Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 385312kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on company_info c  (cost=0.00..660170.03 rows=1289903 width=288) (actual time=0.053..13601.667 rows=1264805 loops=3)
              ->  Index Scan using tech_info_domain_id_key on tech_info t  (cost=0.43..7.37 rows=1 width=1128) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=1 loops=101)
                    Index Cond: (domain_id = d.domain_id)
Planning Time: 0.482 ms
Execution Time: 43173.777 ms
```

enable_hashjoin=on;

```
Gather Merge  (cost=11228582.27..11731772.97 rows=4312762 width=1646) (actual time=155494.221..156547.658 rows=101 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Sort  (cost=11227582.25..11232973.20 rows=2156381 width=1646) (actual time=155487.311..155487.583 rows=34 loops=3)
        Sort Key: c.cmp_web_traff_rank, c.cmp_domain
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 149kB
        Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 137kB
        Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 161kB
        ->  Parallel Hash Left Join  (cost=3727608.55..6379458.52 rows=2156381 width=1646) (actual time=120612.707..155487.262 rows=34 loops=3)
              Hash Cond: (d.domain_id = t.domain_id)
              ->  Parallel Hash Left Join  (cost=693405.12..2303913.60 rows=2156381 width=501) (actual time=32426.682..32845.415 rows=34 loops=3)
                    Hash Cond: (d.domain_id = c.domain_id)
                    ->  Parallel Hash Left Join  (cost=13571.28..1467385.25 rows=2156381 width=221) (actual time=19376.508..19444.711 rows=34 loops=3)
                          Hash Cond: (d.tag_id = m.tag_id)
                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on domain_info d  (cost=0.00..1328299.43 rows=2156381 width=193) (actual time=1082.026..19255.014 rows=34 loops=3)
                                Filter: ((domain_id IS NOT NULL) AND (prospector_id = ANY ('{20881,94259,232564,86408,189655,10654,12916674,12816939,136487,137920,41978,29876,88698,92173,211585,139373,89140,5006,39649,83666,136533,10949,12812242,81684,11873,139736,216078,192526,89299,154159,89204,93744,99332,136447,12832241,82964,137684,81011,86456,47800,89787,138707,86821,88741,139209,89695,10929,89580,92113,248744,93381,137100,13422,135922,139672,89625,32440,138471,139002,12886918,139481,137298,221742,93941,82996,12862710,134327,136711,117993,84739,209561,25124,12907898,156867,25313,205498,162553,89648,137976,137767,137968,137779,12861976,139083,137579,176214,87495,86364,243901,12828901,92564,139901,90791,136781,139073,12861423,12815159,100902,137628,139911,137316}'::integer[])))
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 3433181
                          ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=8564.01..8564.01 rows=246501 width=36) (actual time=106.434..106.435 rows=87381 loops=3)
                                Buckets: 65536  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 3648kB
                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on m_all_tags m  (cost=0.00..8564.01 rows=246501 width=36) (actual time=0.015..31.192 rows=87381 loops=3)
                    ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=652645.60..652645.60 rows=537460 width=288) (actual time=12962.870..12962.871 rows=421602 loops=3)
                          Buckets: 16384  Batches: 128  Memory Usage: 3488kB
                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on company_info c  (cost=0.00..652645.60 rows=537460 width=288) (actual time=0.603..12000.314 rows=421602 loops=3)
              ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=2209142.52..2209142.52 rows=5388152 width=1128) (actual time=87202.693..87202.694 rows=2040639 loops=3)
                    Buckets: 4096  Batches: 4096  Memory Usage: 2208kB
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on tech_info t  (cost=0.00..2209142.52 rows=5388152 width=1128) (actual time=1.921..50208.931 rows=2040639 loops=3)
Planning Time: 0.635 ms
Execution Time: 156547.780 ms
```

Below are the indexes created

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS domain_info_domain_id_idx
    ON prospects_v6.domain_info USING btree
    (domain_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS cmp_info_domain_id_idx
    ON prospects_v6.company_info USING btree
    (domain_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS tech_info_domain_id_idx
    ON prospects_v6.tech_info USING btree
    (domain_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS domain_info_prosp_id_idx
    ON prospects_v6.domain_info USING btree
    (prospector_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Is there any other way to make the query faster? If i turn off enable_hashjoin what will be its effect in db.

Comment: PostgreVersion is 12.7

Comment: @jjanes didnt get your question on ANALYZE

Comment: default_statistics_target value is 100. Didnt execute ANALYZE on all the mentioned tables

Comment: Running ANALYZE reduced time to 5 seconds. I need the execution time to be less than a second as multiple queries with similar conditions will be executed simultaneously

Comment: master.m_all_tags is not used at all, why do you have it in your SQL ?

Comment: Sorry missed it..id column from the master will be used in select. the id column is also btree indexed

Comment: Add the new 5 second execution plan.

Comment: @jjanes Thanks to you. Attaching the execution plan in the main post , it has 45ms execution time and my issue is solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running ANALYZE on all the tables fixed the issues. Attaching the execution plan

````
"  Sort Key: c.cmp_web_traff_rank, c.cmp_domain"
"  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 3072kB"
"  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.84..80709.74 rows=2500 width=1811) (actual time=0.441..31.347 rows=2500 loops=1)"
"        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.42..60405.24 rows=2500 width=1522) (actual time=0.427..23.790 rows=2500 loops=1)"
"              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.99..39616.24 rows=2500 width=253) (actual time=0.413..14.473 rows=2500 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using prospector_id_idx on domain_info d  (cost=0.56..20993.99 rows=2500 width=225) (actual time=0.398..9.105 rows=2500 loops=1)"
"                          Index Cond: (prospector_id = ANY ('{249774,13454209,58615,13325575,75967,19528,12957386,64166,12858867,13427659,65575,33491,30000,160996,73412,13247494,27474,77110,74547,194041,105678,110449,126367,129243,190780,112393,141770,142119,95529,12885584,297705,301822,151802,126853,12918591,13308031,127024,95934,195260,106300,37695,173275,392079,392382,13259977,223723,224588,13464314,236274,236852,406972,139709,33231,266948,279299,53708,6508,25713,14100957,14100996,13191251,13245996,31949,464538,325332,12955296,13296762,50790,341184,14103278,96793,17916,53929,38605,128025,20344,26948,495197,363975,117749,367345,368820,368988,369314,13238078,18780,27343,374906,376181,12954415,86504,377768,268383,379150,97261,12874057,268691,13287317,12907052,27779,23959,385723,50967,12953994,17660,391695,88279,394208,113307,396672,89801,49301,400183,13441946,30548,403900,405187,405776,406624,139127,14095873,13437007,418073,418155,5585,418879,419754,420670,421752,242982,135175,424940,37989,13468838,13432131,101635,46017,12952806,94249,7835,98447,12944904,647246,443863,155123,445651,446062,100234,100342,110735,93286,111124,132044,101134,460286,461070,112933,467275,470514,470780,113740,13639574,476954,481929,138655,13206487,114430,12830087,13193207,282941,13300276,13260416,13269390,497747,497847,12956698,190659,13443972,854661,859445,13533034,863131,503943,13444107,104447,12952629,672006,874248,139838,12871418,13222512,881352,510521,12939571,511669,889263,13615241,13060416,12870982,13431067,115048,135830,13615545,12947731,906573,12591683,13450197,520577,13477615,913034,12861274,12911285,13478070,522975,182549,177366,181998,210880,286104,203659,529113,1122756,12955650,13495947,211556,298509,217416,13557153,545414,172221,184801,138437,548186,548659,302957,550546,307285,193499,310556,561688,563009,165486,170987,1088527,568039,568465,568929,13219546,571500,572558,1331934,13432603,579244,329912,1159071,583877,14098766,214148,136433,332260,588257,13580713,592419,13225329,12899874,597889,343661,13584592,217896,1244063,347824,200700,1270969,615054,616582,617824,618925,359732,170533,626272,240609,12868230,12956434,1330868,13566527,632136,12958979,633371,12954011,13480629,13462685,1341028,12924989,13271743,637571,638263,1344447,14383919,12958224,1346925,13592665,13499671,12958637,1350364,1351518,12878460,1353168,1356134,648078,648771,1359645,14383779,12836580,651758,12955970,13500459,653490,12931375,14346449,1365263,14383753,657390,1367417,658023,13570969,12839669,659930,12893346,13509078,665142,12949763,1378581,12946903,13444736,12947948,1388859,13500406,13304648,13224378,13176369,678525,13177997,1398275,1398720,12834478,695091,695236,13240941,13428970,756263,756752,762011,1428878,764020,1431981,766094,766738,12864212,1438842,769567,1445376,13314057,13285900,1446551,13616440,776855,776924,778308,1453905,14383484,14370166,12938215,1465462,786908,1476949,13513292,790391,1482624,1487739,1499263,1500192,800116,1506408,803446,1511343,1512750,810621,1533052,813830,814873,1548040,1549268,12908547,13207579,827006,830698,832648,12885193,1587223,837585,13624210,840125,12883582,14383374,846445,1597966,13257758,14365777,849489,1599289,1601744,1603178,14159820,13062168,12929459,1611335,12954090,1619403,12957624,13288824,13288130,1638526,1646858,12921512,1657585,13474511,12905539,2297429,1685307,12913752,1702050,2578117,883618,886023,888177,13271262,889120,13470940,12813053,894404,13482679,13529902,13254604,908304,908632,913011,13456947,13455122,918727,13458762,922307,13459197,13447009,923976,925775,12844833,928725,929561,930005,13515373,932079,932817,13520823,13446104,13471973,13499555,940618,941312,13536842,943557,943699,944245,947756,13478143,948787,950834,13475315,4173018,954363,956781,959979,961149,13489951,962270,963379,12958667,965490,965576,967321,13481473,13477990,13531167,13460497,971474,974514,13482339,976995,12913863,13511899,13460223,13515970,3475227,13516985,13462274,680620,12884979,1772681,12898486,12923868,13251529,13247630,987714,989146,990033,2901334,998418,998484,13060867,999731,1001106,1002868,1004087,1005664,13188642,1008984,1009119,1009341,1011693,12957438,1015151,1015224,1017345,1018988,13460301,12890463,1025764,1028733,12911923,12934285,13617414,12954283,12954180,3535138,1040268,12953507,1042193,1042612,12902270,1046476,12953113,1047569,1047930,1048227,1048535,2500544,1052387,2507045,2507656,2514104,1054831,1055588,1056646,2542869,14346038,12947244,1059944,2570471,1060156,1060642,1060721,1061997,12921730,13306625,2594612,1062766,1066670,1067613,12917484,1069411,2671102,2676040,2687659,2690698,1076359,1077921,13236519,13935639,1079025,2745346,1080458,1080871,2765613,13436129,1087281,1087358,14098906,2843788,1090048,12954839,1092131,13227783,12879696,1095765,1095833,1095883,1096651,1096905,12945247,12818980,2869020,13242631,2871141,1100880,2871272,2871341,13431326,1101513,2871905,1102270,2872799,2873363,1103829,12953488,14353809,1105388,14353806,1107074,12954869,1108511,12959279,12908891,13254517,12953925,2883033,2884973,1115477,13641116,2887190,12935206,1118378,1119036,2889656,2890200,1121109,1123374,12898877,2900938,2902784,1125320,2909589,1126879,2934729,2948148,1130616,12883451,2976946,2998347,1136656,13206781,1137109,12953753,1138243,3028392,14365657,3048119,3061405,4928837,3072595,1145607,3089029,3097876,13438343,3108237,1151039,3162398,3168257,3169241,1156404,3239087,1163060,14333328,1164041,1165581,1168433,1169083,3320063,3320735,3324227,12853868,3343704,14330355,1174748,3372049,1176229,12958436,1178592,1179211,3410088,3450911,3457792,3469149,3476786,14034443,3483450,3487896,1187630,1188139,1189224,13624430,3541705,3542127,1191420,3556516,1192643,12896095,3601389,1197540,13240679,1204518,3662784,1206656,1207160,3690259,1207884,3695757,3699032,1209608,1211768,1214752,14180083,3771241,1220344,1220755,1220852,3801564,1222837,3825095,12922890,1224922,3837484,3855080,1227781,3880711,3886163,1230717,3899027,1232307,3902593,1232993,1234662,1235021,1236616,3942111,1236991,1237048,1237500,3967358,3979002,4002410,4017867,4028206,4046468,4057599,1248481,4071428,1250251,1251610,1251866,1252088,1255585,1255940,4147536,4151437,12947313,4157063,4160102,14022023,4208129,1265157,1265654,1266607,1449453,4241057,4247971,1269903,1271900,1272253,4281458,1273143,1859919,1862327,1273778,1275722,2537472,2577981,3234918,3253686,1277774,13443208,1277865,3933994,3939480,3948809,3953500,4595975,4601587,1281198,1282211,1282502,4379786,4381033,4386454,5397182,5404930,5405775,5407456,5407510,4397957,1288111,5496980,5497404,5497728,5497749,5497810,5497831,5497847,5497955,5497960,5498108,5498179,5498233,5499505,5499583,5499838,5500192,5500214,5500221,5500306,5500450,5500476,5500648,5500714,5500835,5501077,5501092,5501173,5501270,5501291,5501547,5501638,5501839,5501995,5502247,5502636,5502727,5504369,5533610,5548929,5551432,5553460,5556052,5558599,5559676,5570906,1289021,3272995,1289448,12926638,1290831,12953506,14161779,1293273,4468088,1296180,4495245,5613923,5613925,1299992,1300434,1300661,1301697,1369030,1384513,1302969,4543465,4544706,14096142,4567961,1307374,1308486,1309560,2166213,4614255,2574449,2578595,2881788,3248509,3250497,1312818,3255541,3257897,3267364,3921554,3921729,4581134,4588756,4599772,4619339,4622831,4635718,12876971,1315493,5230668,1315807,4662959,4678185,4692758,5390842,5393561,5399542,5399838,5404072,4712291,4725991,5496410,5496483,5496855,5497347,5497407,5497412,5497419,5497521,5497671,5497809,5497841,5497856,5497914,5497995,5498047,5498132,5499582,5499916,5499929,5500320,5500407,5500492,5500774,5500852,5501303,5501389,5501403,5501419,5501664,5501871,5501891,5501954,5502231,5502264,5502651,5502734,5526486,5528156,5531099,5547765,5559899,5572915,5575892,2549142,4754694,12828290,4787741,4792666,1326755,1327164,936837,5613884,4867267,4870169,4873244,1330547,4882082,5525997,1335908,1372978,1378861,1387613,1396839,4924866,1335432,1337834,2593169,2603796,2612963,2618476,2622728,4974711,2626020,4976567,3286376,3301176,4982756,3316346,3954509,3968501,3976509,3981891,3987746,4646161,4659686,1340885,5035730,5045470,5393472,5395166,5401711,5403175,5403355,5403506,5405896,12875565,5057862,5058603,5064371,5469576,5496642,5497334,5497388,5497478,5497501,5497759,5497764,5497788,5497849,5497887,5497954,5498051,5498256,5499573,5499578,5499618,5499703,5499736,5499875,5499900,5499949,5500052,5500074,5500184,5500185,5500259,5500292,5500345,5500388,5500575,5500744,5500931,5501100,5501144,5501206,5501229,5501385,5501499,5501670,5501702,5502323,5502389,5502546,5502595,5502700,5502705,5506778,5507274,5507589,5509896,5516686,5517891,5523796,5532819,5533390,5540950,5543228,5545866,5554605,5555022,5566430,5566512,5571496,5578225,5582225,5583881,5091504,5092577,14329873,13246792,522098,14094808,5132700,13436508,13259100,5151792,741162,5169080,1354385,5613885,5186990,1356282,1354210,1357655,1396163,12895247,1360347,12908300,13545092,12944740,2600060,13565843,2619306,2619843,3333182,3971836,3974469,3998393,5224940,4634111,4640855,4653325,4673376,5225920,5496766,13544524,5393244,5393476,5398570,5399687,5401111,5466014,5496674,5497459,5497551,5497818,5498077,5499613,5499746,5499860,5499925,5499928,5500028,5500241,5500406,5500484,5500511,5500603,5500647,5501070,5501278,5501485,5501575,5501646,5501881,5501917,5501982,5502015,5502125,5502189,5502275,5502388,5502454,5502455,5502565,5502719,5502729,13251580,5510131,5515019,5516541,5521065,5527149,5532588,5533117,5535047,5535400,5538718,5549287,5552699,5558562,5559116,5559649,5573268,5574283,5575075,5585342,5585747,1374643,12858811,5251654,12895556,5613929,12957154,1357335,1382841,12957204,1384360,1384770,1385386,1893120,2646338,3327169,3341982,3363847,3369998,4020079,4032510,4036328,4037402,4038482,4666906,4681505,4684347,4712222,4712386,5390390,5391723,5401467,5403484,5403739,12959073,1399002,5496277,5497137,5497387,5497520,5497908,5498005,5498090,5498168,5498252,5498258,5499599,5499819,5499913,5499951,5500309,5500310,5500315,5500422,5500423,5500478,5500548,5500642,5500670,5500962,5501123,5501239,5501532,5501582,5501800,5502039,5502284,5502485,5502506,5502598,5502649,5502650,5502663,5502717,5506428,5507340,5534388,5534476,5535543,5546045,5548947,5552291,5557606,5557866,5558584,5566467,5571630,5572730,5578704,1400780,12938837,1402905,12890521,12890948,1408760,12956996,12956794,13205341,13260479,12891302,1180380,12921939,1419459,1420502,1424909,1426484,1426659,13202001,13256920,1427026,5280723,1428129,13202551,13202443,5281540,12919351,13260757,12949979,12958841,5286785,1441250,1442223,1443597,13199859,13306791,1444812,367001,12916761,12916893,12937290,5291900,12955924,12845903,1449962,14353324,12886028,5513714,5296349,5518698,5298157,1459216,13195985,1370741,1397142,1461032,13248533,1464900,5303104,5303802,5304383,2136295,12955655,1472132,1472386,2504651,2510465,2514014,2525739,2526880,2528220,2541057,2543049,3210558,3225075,3240885,3243480,3883018,3885694,4543564,4550848,4557717,4567625,4583573,5308407,12934557,1479888,12880743,12958484,12955206,1480562,5496775,1481974,12881115,13190135,5311362,1484786,13297960,5312141,5312351,5396251,5398059,1486702,5405988,1487020,12839223,1488557,5314876,5496734,1491171,5496816,5496947,5497053,5497226,5497345,5497364,5497399,5497509,5497574,5497675,5497724,5497840,5499947,5500161,5500336,5500387,5500469,5500475,5500622,5500723,5500770,5500792,5501127,5501281,5501322,5501841,5501943,5502096,5502114,5502249,5502277,5502365,5502366,5502382,5502415,5502556,5520464,5527123,5532878,5532925,5545325,5550114,5552352,5556635,5556890,5562210,5575044,5578371,5316281,1493501,13350765,1494366,13294533,13241754,13351132,1498142,12958416,12910444,1501111,12954822,5576689,13186237,5322893,1505281,927273,1505531,1506390,1506869,5324593,5324907,12946832,1510893,1331130,5326077,1356186,1398680,12945545,1514651,13287457,1518101,1518425,1520556,12874150,1521466,1522133,1523185,1523352,1524523,12908145,2506990,2512621,1527155,12961580,3202208,3215661,3216114,3219384,3220833,3232124,3237597,3241243,3879572,3888499,3893463,3907721,4577933,13232013,4587175,12906231,13286009,1535256,1535401,12830574,12872754,12930593,13286594,1538032,12954146,1540529,12875049,5398793,5400624,5406518,13181765,5496695,5496997,5497471,5497479,5497563,5497566,5497583,5497606,5497714,5497716,5497837,5499576,5499579,5499634,5499650,5500085,5500298,5500340,5500383,5500517,5500615,5500796,5500806,5500823,5501021,5501039,5501146,5501210,5501366,5501434,5501470,5501885,5501906,5501970,5502209,5502241,5502283,5502446,5502582,5502737,5506328,5526829,5528294,5529692,5533691,5535944,5538829,5539981,5540079,5545600,5548020,5548182,5550326,5556007,5565754,5569460,5576491,5581269,13182204,1547625,13182901,1551136,1557492,1558662,12957765,12952890,12862473,12926047,12817771,12952805,5958818,2641477,2650270,2654849,2657115,3344015,13014004,3365703,3367989,3371620,12952730,1570296,4036744,4037156,4665256,13215287,12925362,1574158,1574455,1574802,1575182,12934084,5357672,1575937,12943244,12864038,5393668,5394608,5399988,5405302,13181016,13149639,6217688,13220752,5496497,5496650,5497377,5497380,5497431,5497437,5497567,5497704,5497867,5497897,5498054,5498100,5498200,5498204,5499525,5499751,5499852,5499858,5500026,5500121,5500269,5500344,5500593,5500713,5500756,5501323,5501432,5501491,5501512,5501583,5501604,5501615,5501801,5502063,5502076,5502102,5502239,5502597,5514335,5516731,5517390,5527904,5532418,5533431,5534118,5537838,5538206,5540811,5548264,5551028,5552627,5552908,5556802,5557699,5558176,5569123,5577891,5585333,13435046,13434822,13434731,5364055,12953231,13131943,12900949,13434082,12929213,12869235,5368104,12868948,5368261,1591395,684901,795268,12868630,5370552,1593299,12944265,1181412,12944256,13225925,1334457,1342010,1400312,1473893,13284397,1598420,12944864,1600994,2675615,2681231,2681240,2691883,2692684,2696817,2699335,2704951,3379279,3381468,3381929,3389895,4050211,4052448,4068042,4069785,4087237,4714468,4716201,4737419,4758454,5383276,5383839,5385551,13436377,13332198,1609012,5390812,5398877,5401629,13275348,1610306,1612473,5389028,1614264,1614419,5497123,5497360,5497659,5497721,5497770,5497872,5499686,5499933,5499991,5500144,5500153,5500175,5500187,5500231,5500319,5500342,5500488,5500499,5500752,5501404,5501493,5501544,5501658,5501815,5501987,5502127,5502273,5502433,5502510,5502523,5502531,5502618,5502635,5505358,5514783,5517745,5531655,5537264,5538927,5539481,5540810,5541115,5543019,5548157,5548329,5552288,5553510,5554209,5557027,5560190,5574735,5585552,1615499,12880108,1618641,1620177,1620832,12892628,13187968,13211237,1628187,1629156,1629316,12952721,7360693,5407518,13427673,1381592,14243001,1636702,1637490,7502044,5421821,5423530,1642699,1643502,1930678,13590723,13634917,1648120,13626487,2680620,2694271,2694933,2695926,2697930,2702714,3362991,3376600,3385314,3395464,1650584,3417642,3418412,4046073,4054320,4064077,4064789,4072593,4074103,4078029,4705357,4716056,4723960,4725513,4730598,1653419,13666523,1655693,1656558,13615641,1660648,5393808,5395717,5395868,5396081,5396974,5406517,5407218,13624905,1665337,1666328,5496479,5497487,5497593,5497667,5497727,5498188,5498249,5499508,5499562,5499627,5499850,5499923,5500076,5500227,5500251,5500436,5500443,5500580,5500638,5500697,5501170,5501353,5501374,5501462,5501483,5501560,5501726,5501835,5502024,5502044,5502051,5502232,5502381,5502460,5502462,5502474,5502575,5502628,5502712,5504333,5510884,5521346,5523137,5527250,5527807,5527869,5528570,5534156,5537660,5541698,5555458,5555478,5556035,5565148,5575706,3400709,4733057,1667909,1670233,1670560,1671606,1673758,13619962,1675460,1675933,1676354,1679299,13911907,1342235,1342606,1356006,1356861,1371834,1372432,1689414,13592768,13591571,1693140,1695202,1696485,1700798,1701691,13636165,2734960,2741565,3411583,3414209,3435245,3441038,3447685,4090281,4101416,4119058,4755369,4775782,4780879,4783075,4785411,4785616,4795085,5390723,5391177,5392455,5392690,5400604,5404572,5405962,5613920,9042027,5436984,5439284,1720126,1720475,5440956,5497134,5497417,5497526,5497610,5497789,5498044,5498240,5498269,5499558,5499592,5499609,5499614,5499664,5499714,5499823,5500039,5500155,5500284,5500445,5500715,5500952,5501004,5501022,5501037,5501041,5501058,5501098,5501539,5501571,5501832,5502309,5502477,5502502,5502614,5502713,5536233,5540634,5540673,5541498,5544451,5551117,5551304,5555049,5558417,5559164,5566653,5571694,5572073,5574145,5574472,5578183,13669616,1722798,1723231,1725899,13621133,1728931,1729988,13618234,1112169,13615558,1333270,1342991,1355371,13622328,13685616,13616710,1936343,13628087,13646403,2723223,2736467,13648529,3448118,3454396,3454564,4083057,4108793,4113628,4125374,4750444,4757000,4765865,4772334,4776361,4793988,5496755,1739338,5393001,5398778,5399768,5402206,5613899,5496785,5497562,5497701,5497845,5497868,5497963,5498018,5499584,5499824,5499917,5500369,5500414,5500453,5500578,5500778,5500867,5500901,5500922,5500978,5500989,5501084,5501478,5501821,5501859,5501942,5502018,5502202,5502505,5502631,5502653,5510982,5514479,5522840,5529512,5531785,5532262,5532352,5540875,5545916,5548755,5555655,5558515,5564487,5573065,5574486,5574492,5580255,1742156,783636,14020414,1332240,1341561,1344992,1386564,1387264,1527382,5501687,14022375,5502491,5505771,14098876,5508607,1745108,5510318,5513540,5514427,2752961,2767031,2773294,2787221,2787237,2788863,14099490,3475296,3478129,3494295,5521833,4164045,4173931,4802639,5523649,4822630,12857681,13355992,13080567,14115469,13414016,12848135,13362174,13201521,13445939,400405,12957131,446467,12998637,13034285,12994092,12909427,12994045,12875174,12874684,13154282,13094526,13175005,13151728,13334828,14132071,12848777,13046598,735163,764594,13320721,13212008,828463,13249584,13453154,13184726,12844485,14246754,13092287,13350305,12911218,13086692,13038246,930174,13201006,12988630,12970557,14105335,13079738,14105346,12987160,13055205,5392458,13079850,5394222,13158176,12989207,13083254,13051342,1240782,1241904,13247560,13012044,1351450,1355377,14026767,1371336,1384051,1385834,1395414,1395632,1397373,1398044,1398803,13130441,13052117,1418600,1419704,1421115,1424309,1428540,12928053,1453308,1470163,1472041,13253586,13244518,1515552,13113077,1536951,1549953,13191681,1589066,1593344,1622831,1624761,1643959,1661565,1666794,13008608,13252139,12929012,5496435,5496477,5497454,5497571,5497873,5497902,5498068,5498128,5498219,5499510,5499603,5499611,5499628,5499783,5500240,5500296,5500308,5500455,5500619,5500709,5500889,5501030,5501186,5501213,5501335,5501427,5501536,5501555,5501601,13462775,5501752,5501753,5501844,5501998,5502109,5502193,5502245,5502418,5502457,5502498,5502602,5502639,5502709,5502725,5509266,5509733,5528057,5531290,5535124,5539925,5540541,5544304,5547148,5553730,5554591,5558222,5558556,5571227,5572675,5576432,13051953,12841622,13077831,12847137,14102801,13425942,12989790,12864221,13133258,13204480,13185600,13000174,13211043,13182917,13199930,12820384,12820917,12873813,13027894,13026562,13066659,1843008,1843250,13033843,1844069,13247029,1844096,13001728,13248035,1845631,1845770,13151368,13222939,13050863,12940708,2463039,12909170,12931592,13068530,2481922,12824319,12824635,13148280,2501895,2501991,2502015,2502120,13266152,2503245,2503970,2504147,2504212,2504486,2506043,2506305,2506801,2507289,2507758,2507775,2508141,2508299,2508300,2508522,12975688,2508699,2509330,2509478,2509770,2509952,2510024,2510285,2510469,2510600,2510784,2510869,2511058,2511893,2511898,2512590,2514363,2514369,2514405,2514514,2516234,2516425,13034994,2516962,2517331,2517953,2518065,2518088,2520390,2520951,2521034,2521079,2521815,2521876,2522729,2523311,2523734,2524606,2525563,13027251,2526021,2527720,2527952,2527986,2528032,2529490,2529540,2529558,2529928,2530296,2530645,2530820,14023375,2531043,2531259,2531944,2531978,2532491,2532529,2532794,2533027,2533110,2533167,2533387,2533440,2533809,2534414,2534556,13330510,2535401,2535529,2536825,2536827,2537490,2537672,13382985,2538154,2538950,2539498,2540786,2541296,2541602,2542669,2542943,2544197,2872694,12865020,13109380,12971381,13088590,3867734,3867776,3867788,3868668,3869156,3869364,3869695,3870831,3876884,3877170,3877637,3877658,3877902,3878071,3878411,13254082,3878481,3879074,3879657,3880949,3882748,3882881,3884445,3884449,3884693,13009706,3885107,3885767,3887479,3888524,3888572,3888779}'::integer[]))"
"                          Filter: (domain_id IS NOT NULL)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using m_all_tags_pkey on m_all_tags m  (cost=0.42..7.45 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=2500)"
"                          Index Cond: (tag_id = d.tag_id)"
"              ->  Index Scan using tech_info_domain_id_key on tech_info t  (cost=0.43..8.32 rows=1 width=1277) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=2500)"
"                    Index Cond: (domain_id = d.domain_id)"
"        ->  Index Scan using cmp_info_p_key on company_info c  (cost=0.43..8.12 rows=1 width=287) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=2500)"
"              Index Cond: (domain_id = d.domain_id)"
"Planning Time: 2.097 ms"
"Execution Time: 45.727 ms"```
````