# Bitmap Heap Scan instead of Index Scan causing slow query

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I am running the below query

```
select d.cmp_domain AS "domain",
       c.state AS "state",
   c.country AS "country",
   c.regions AS "regions",
   t.*
   m.tags from
   prospects_v6.domain_info d
   left join master.m_all_tags m using(tag_id)
   left join prospects_v6.tech_info t on t.domain_id = d.domain_id
   left join prospects_v6.company_info c on c.domain_id = d.domain_id where
   d.domain_id is not null
   and d.prospector_id in (
       '20881',
       '94259',
       '232564',
       '86408',
       '189655',
       '10654',
       '12916674',
       '12816939',
       '136487',
       '137920',
       '41978',
       '29876',
       '88698',
       '92173',
       '211585',
       '139373',
       '89140',
       '5006',
       '39649',
       '83666',
       '136533',
       '10949',
       '12812242',
       '81684',
       '11873',
       '139736',
       '216078',
       '192526',
       '89299',
       '154159',
       '89204',
       '93744',
       '99332',
       '136447',
       '12832241',
       '82964',
       '137684',
       '81011',
       '86456',
       '47800',
       '89787',
       '138707',
       '86821',
       '88741',
       '139209',
       '89695',
       '10929',
       '89580',
       '92113',
       '248744',
       '93381',
       '137100') order by c.domain asc;
```

This is my explain analyze output

```
"        Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1477kB"
"        Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1715kB"
"        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=43.95..43927.18 rows=1042 width=1811) (actual time=7871.695..84733.497 rows=833 loops=3)"
"              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=43.52..35650.99 rows=1042 width=1522) (actual time=7871.662..84418.637 rows=833 loops=3)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=43.09..27026.15 rows=1042 width=253) (actual time=7867.920..83465.862 rows=833 loops=3)"
"                          ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on domain_info d  (cost=42.66..19859.59 rows=1042 width=225) (actual time=7867.876..83373.269 rows=833 loops=3)"
"                                Recheck Cond: (prospector_id = ANY ('{249774,13454209,}'::integer[]))"
"                                Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 1795888"
"                                Filter: (domain_id IS NOT NULL)"
"                                Heap Blocks: lossy=70222"
"                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on prosp_id_idx  (cost=0.00..42.04 rows=3968 width=0) (actual time=7250.476..7250.476 rows=1241025160 loops=1)"
"                                      Index Cond: (prospector_id = ANY ('{249774,13454209,58615,13325575,75967,19528,12957386,64166,}'::integer[]))"
"                          ->  Index Scan using m_all_tags_pkey on m_all_tags m  (cost=0.42..6.88 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.105..0.105 rows=1 loops=2500)"
"                                Index Cond: (tag_id = d.tag_id)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using tech_info_domain_id_idx on tech_info t  (cost=0.43..8.28 rows=1 width=1277) (actual time=1.132..1.132 rows=1 loops=2500)"
"                          Index Cond: (domain_id = d.domain_id)"
"              ->  Index Scan using max_domainid_idx on company_info c  (cost=0.43..7.94 rows=1 width=287) (actual time=0.374..0.374 rows=0 loops=2500)"
"                    Index Cond: (domain_id = d.domain_id)"
"Planning Time: 4.279 ms"
"Execution Time: 84760.714 ms"
```

Earlier the same query was running in 500 msec..now it takes longer. I am running an ANALYZE on all the tables. How to over come the Bitmap heap scan here.There are indexes in all the join columns..
this is the link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70344772/slow-query-in-postgres-while-joining-tables-with-10m-rows-all-join-column-indexe][1] which I posted earlier. There is a BRIN index on prospector_id in domain_info table.

Edit 1: After dropping BRIN index below is the explain plan

```
"Gather Merge  (cost=59804.00..59973.17 rows=1471 width=1812) (actual time=42.044..46.377 rows=2500 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 1"
"  Workers Launched: 1"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=58803.99..58807.67 rows=1471 width=1812) (actual time=32.844..33.020 rows=1250 loops=2)"
"        Sort Key: c.cmp_domain"
"        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2411kB"
"        Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2333kB"
"        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=10752.16..58726.60 rows=1471 width=1812) (actual time=6.119..27.333 rows=1250 loops=2)"
"              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=10751.73..47043.04 rows=1471 width=1523) (actual time=6.100..20.926 rows=1250 loops=2)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=10751.30..34867.27 rows=1471 width=254) (actual time=6.076..13.200 rows=1250 loops=2)"
"                          ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on domain_info d  (cost=10750.88..24750.18 rows=1471 width=226) (actual time=6.054..8.478 rows=1250 loops=2)"
"                                Recheck Cond: (prospector_id = ANY ('{249774,13454209}'::integer[]))"
"                                Filter: (domain_id IS NOT NULL)"
"                                Heap Blocks: exact=1107"
"                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on prospector_id_idx  (cost=0.00..10750.25 rows=2500 width=0) (actual time=9.439..9.439 rows=2500 loops=1)"
"                                      Index Cond: (prospector_id = ANY ('{249774,13454209}'::integer[]))"
"                          ->  Index Scan using m_all_tags_pkey on m_all_tags m  (cost=0.42..6.88 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=2500)"
"                                Index Cond: (tag_id = d.tag_id)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using tech_info_domain_id_idx on tech_info t  (cost=0.43..8.28 rows=1 width=1277) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=2500)"
"                          Index Cond: (domain_id = d.domain_id)"
"              ->  Index Scan using max_domainid_idx on company_info c  (cost=0.43..7.94 rows=1 width=287) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=2500)"
"                    Index Cond: (domain_id = d.domain_id)"
"Planning Time: 4.403 ms"
"Execution Time: 47.726 ms"
```

Why there is Parallel Bitmap heap scan instead of index scan.

Comment: "                                Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 1795888"
That's your problem, could you add the missing fields to the index? And what indexes do you have?

Comment: CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS domain_info_domain_id_idx  ON prospects_v6.domain_info USING btree(domain_id ASC NULLS LAST) TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS cmp_info_domain_id_idx ON prospects_v6.company_info USING btree(domain_id ASC NULLS LAST) TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS tech_info_domain_id_idx ON prospects_v6.tech_info USING btree(domain_id ASC NULLS LAST) TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS domain_info_prosp_id_idx ON prospects_v6.domain_info USING btree(prospector_id ASC NULLS LAST) TABLESPACE pg_default;

Comment: Double check your plan that it was copied and pasted correctly.  I don't see how it is possible for a bitmap of rows=1241025160 to visit only 70222 pages.

Comment: btree index on prospector_id,domain_id,cmp_domain,tag_id as in the above comment..

Comment: There is a BRIN index on prospector_id in domain_info table. will that be the cause of these lossy blocks

Comment: Add the domain_id to your index: CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS domain_info_prosp_id__domain_id_idx ON prospects_v6.domain_info USING btree(prospector_id ASC NULLS LAST, domain_id) ; This should change to query plan

Comment: creating the above index didnt help

Comment: If you don't want to use bitmap scans, then certainly don't create BRIN indexes.  That is the only thing they are capable of.

Comment: I dropped the BRIN index. Attached the explain plan in main post. Query is faster now. But why do I see Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan Instead of Index Scan still